# Is it possible to pass a variable from JavaScript to Django?

Tags: javascript, django

Hello guys I'm was trying to find some examples trying to find a variable from JavaScript to Django last night but I could not find anything.

The only examples I could find were about Ajax, I wonder if it's possible to use JavaScript or only Ajax.

If it's possible to use it can you guys could give me a simple example to achieve this?

I only want to pass a variable to Django but I have no idea how to do it

Thank you

Comment: Ajax is just the more common method of performing a POST request which is what you really need. But then there are plenty of tutorials on ajax posting in javascript..

Comment: JavaScript is on the browser, Django on the server. You can't pass variables between the two, unless you send a HTTP request. There are multiple methods to do requests from a browser to the server: forms, links, Ajax. Most of the time, if you're using JavaScript, you'll want to use Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Some basics:

- JavaScript runs in the browser, its variables exist only there
- Django runs on the server, its variables exist only there
- They communicate using HTTP, which uses requests from the browser to the server that get responses back
- "Ajax" is a strange name for a specific way to send a request *from JavaScript*, using the also strangely named XMLHttpRequest function. So Ajax is a thing you do in JavaScript.

In short, yes you use Ajax to send a request to the server. That request should include the variable's value (e.g. as a parameter). Then Django should have a view that receives that request, reads the parameter, and does with it whatever it wants.